# chronicle directory-listing.cq4t release

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I've upgraded chronicle-queue binaries to the latest version and notice a new file (probably it's not that new but I haven't seen it before) - directory-listing.cq4t.

I have a test creating a regular queue with `SingleChronicleQueueBuilder` then doing some operations and closing it. As the last step I'm force-deleting the whole folder with the data.

Problem is that `directory-listing.cq4t` is locked by java process even when queue is already closed. Note that data file itself is deleted without any problems.

There is a test in chronicle code base `SingleChronicleQueueTest.shouldCreateQueueInCurrentDirectory` which can demonstrate the above behavior as file is not being deleted and delete() call returns false (but result is never asserted)

Is it a known problem or I’m doing it wrong? (queue release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the bug-report. This looks like an oversight where the directory listing was not being closed correctly.

I've fixed that problem in master. Can you build the latest from github and re-test?

Comment: Looks great, thank you for the fix (tested with 4.6.58-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Could you please also check shouldAllowDirectoryToBeDeletedWhenQueueIsClosed test. It's working fine as it is but if you add writing and then reading (and it's because of the reading) then data file .cq4 remains locked and test start failing.

Comment: Could you raise a github issue please?